# Get raw data from QImage

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a QImage that I built from a pixmap something like the following:

```
QPixmap fullPmap = topItem->pixmap();
fullPmap = fullPmap.copy(isec.toRect());
QImage chip = fullPmap.toImage();
```

This is basically intersecting with a rectangle on screen to crop the image to a chipped size.

I now need to get the character array representing that data back from chip.

How can I do this?

I tried something like this:

```
  unsigned char * data = chip.bits();
```

And when I display "data" I get a completely distorted image, nothing like my actual chip.

fullPmap is an RGB image if that matters. I have some code that I am using to convert it to grayscale:

```
QRgb col;
int gray;
for (int i = 0; i < chip.width(); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < chip.height(); ++j)
    {
        col = chip.pixel(i, j);
        gray = qGray(col);
        chip.setPixel(i, j, qRgb(gray, gray, gray));
    }
}
```

Which I don't really like, but it seemed like the easiest way to do such a thing.

Displaying the data that is returned from bits() looks like this:

```
imwidth = chip.width();
imheight = chip.height();
QImage *qi = new QImage(imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_RGB32);
//  #pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0 ; i < imheight ; i++)
    for (int j = 0 ; j < imwidth ; j++)
    {
        qi->setPixel(j,i,qRgb(data[i*imwidth + j],data[i*imwidth + j],data[i*imwidth + j]));
    }
```

Comment: As in it looks like snow - nothing like the original chip

Comment: How do you "display" the data returned from bits()?

Comment: Edited to add the display code. However, this is not exactly what I want to do with data anyway...I am trying to ship data off to a 3rd party function that will use data as an input and ship back a different unsigned char * array, which I know how to display.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When dealing with raw image data, you need to be aware of some basic issues:

- What is the format or layout of pixel
  data. The QImage converted from
  QPixmap is not necessarily always in
  RGB888 or RGB32. Call
  QImage::format() and deal with
  different layout differently.
  Especially with RGB32 family, you
  need to make sure you access them in
  right byte order (endian).
- The bytes are not always layout
  exactly that many bytes to hold the
  pixels of the line. Typically a line
  will have more bytes than it's
  needed. Use QImage::bytesPerLine() to
  find out and advance the pointer by
  that many bytes when going to the
  next line. This is probably your issue
  in the building of the display image.
- QImage::pixel() and setPixel() are
  really slow. Get/set pixel values
  from raw pixel buffer if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the bytes per line. That was the problem it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
m_image =  new QImage(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT, QImage::Format_RGB32);
m_image->fill(Qt::white);
int rawDataCount = 0;
for (int y = 0;y<IMAGE_HEIGHT;y++)
{
    uint* line = (uint*)m_image->scanLine(y);
    for (int x=0;x<IMAGE_WIDTH;x++)
    {
        WORD temp = cameraZero[rawDataCount++];
        BYTE value = temp >> 2;
        QColor grey(value,value,value); 
        line[x] = qRgba(value,value,value,100);
    }
}
```

where cameraZero holds a list of pixel values.

Comment: where does "cameraZero" gets declared?
(value,value,value) results in one color?