# Error when converting Qimage to Mat opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

When I convert a QImage to cv::Mat the Mat comes out blurred.

This is the code that converts it:

```
QPixmap pixmap(*ui->imgLabel->pixmap());
QImage image = pixmap.toImage();

image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);

Mat matImage = Mat(image.height(), image.width(), CV_8UC3, image.scanLine(0));
```

This is the original image zoomed:

[image]

This is the image created:

[image]

Grateful for any help.

Comment: One is colour and one is b/w is this intentional?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810970/get-raw-data-from-qimage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know QT, but have you tried ready solutions from WEB? For example, from [this link](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/QImage-to-OpenCV-td5121181.html) I found another method of conversion:

```
Mat qimage2mat(const QImage& qimage) {
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(qimage.height(), qimage.width(), CV_8UC4, (uchar*)qimage.bits(), qimage.bytesPerLine());
    cv::Mat mat2 = cv::Mat(mat.rows, mat.cols, CV_8UC3 );
    int from_to[] = { 0,0,  1,1,  2,2 };
    cv::mixChannels( &mat, 1, &mat2, 1, from_to, 3 );
    return mat2;
};
```