# Convert QImage BGR888 to Mat (OpenCV) in Python

Tags: python, opencv, mat, qimage, image-conversion

I'm trying to convert a QImage into Mat format (to save a video from a sequence of QImage) in Python.

I've been trying the different solutions proposed online, such as the ones described here:

[PyQt/PySide: How do I convert QImage into OpenCV's MAT format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406149/pyqt-pyside-how-do-i-convert-qimage-into-opencvs-mat-format)

https://code-examples.net/en/q/12faee7

One of this solution is the following one:

```
def convertQImageToMat(incomingImage):
        incomingImage = incomingImage.convertToFormat(4)
        width = incomingImage.width()
        height = incomingImage.height()
        ptr = incomingImage.bits()
        ptr.setsize(incomingImage.byteCount())
        arr = np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 4)  #  Copies the data
        return arr
```

But when trying this solution, I end up with a black video of 105KB containing no frame (whatever the number of frames that I write to my cv2.VideoWriter).

If I try this other solution:

```
def convertQImageToMat(incomingImage):
        incomingImage = incomingImage.convertToFormat(QImage.Format.Format_BGR888)
        width = incomingImage.width()
        height = incomingImage.height()
        ptr = incomingImage.constBits()
        arr = np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 4) 
        return arr
```

I then end up with this error:

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (3060,5440,4)`

And no video is then produced (because the above error occurs during frame format conversion, before the cv2.VideoWrite function)

I believe these erros may be due to the non-standard initial format of my QImage, which is as follow:

`img = QImage(self.buf, self.width, self.height, (self.width * 24 + 31) // 32 * 4, QImage.Format_BGR888)`

I've seen here a solution to convert a BGR888 QImage into Mat format ([Error when converting Qimage to Mat opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903587/error-when-converting-qimage-to-mat-opencv)), but this solution is in C++, which I don't master.

Anyone here have already tried to convert such a BGR888 QImage into Mat in Python, or knows how to convert the c++ code provided in the above link into Python?

Many thanks in advance for your help

**EDIT 27/04/2022 13:08**

I found a way using a solution I found here (https://devdreamz.com/question/158707-in-pyqt-how-do-i-convert-qimage-to-a-list-of-pixels). Here is the edited function:

```
def convertQImageToMat(incomingImage):
        incomingImage = incomingImage.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGBX8888)
        ptr = incomingImage.constBits()
        ptr.setsize(incomingImage.byteCount())
        cv_im_in = np.array(ptr, copy=True).reshape(incomingImage.height(), incomingImage.width(), 4)
        cv_im_in = cv2.cvtColor(cv_im_in, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
        return cv_im_in
```

This works fine, however, I am now wondering whether convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGBX8888) alters or not my image (since its initial format is BGR888). If someone can confirm that this does not change anything, then I could call this a solved issue.

Comment: you have to give VideoWriter the size of the expected frames at creation, and all frames you give to `write()` have to be that size. I'm guessing that's not the case?

Comment: No no that's the case, VideoWriter is given the size of the frames, that's not an issue here. This second part of the code (VideoWriter) is not copied here because it's working fine. So far the trick I have found is to save each of my QImage to a jpg (physically, on the hardrive), and then to load each of these jpg images with cv2.imread, and create the video with VideoWriter. This works fine, video is perfect, but this is super long (saving image physically and reloading them is longer than converting them from QImage to Mat directly)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have found a working solution and edited my initial post. Could you confirm me that this solution is not altering/modifying my initial image? The video produced looks great, but I'd like to ensure color fidelity (i.e., I don't want this solution to modify the property of the image)

Comment: imwrite+imread are a hack that contains an implicit cvtColor in the imread. you could have issues with the number of channels or the memory layout. -- I'm not familiar enough with Qt's python bindings to give an opinion on the Qt side.