# Save QImage to array of bytes

Tags: c++, qt

I need to open an image and store it bytes into normal array. Only for opening and getting byte data i can use Qt, for everything else I need to use plain c++. Problem is that I don't know how to do it. Already I know about that:

```
QImage image;
QByteArray ba;
QBuffer buffer(&ba);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes image into ba in PNG format
```

But to be honest I don't understand what it does. What I plan to do is opening image, store it data to QByteArray and then write it data to normal array.

Can someone help me understand how to do it ?

Comment: You can access image's raw data using `bits()`, `scanLine(int)` or other similar methods. Take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810970/get-raw-data-from-qimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810970/get-raw-data-from-qimage)

Comment: What do you call a "normal array"? I think what you want is to convert `QImage` to "normal array"

Comment: Sorry for that "normal". Naturally I was thinking about unsigned char array. And exactly I want to convert my image to unsigned char array, so I could keep image bytes in it

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char>` or `unsigned char[]`?

Comment: unsigned char[]

Comment: @gawron103 Did you use my solution?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes i tried but I got error about invalid conversion from 'uchar* {aha unsigned char*}' to 'size_t {aka unsigned int}'.

Comment: size_t? I find it strange, you could show me the code that you have used and which compiler you use.

Comment: I think you've misapplied my code.

Comment: Oh sorry, looked at wrong error. I've got segmentation error with your solution. But probably there's my mistake. How can I send you my code ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you are asking "how" to do it or trying to understand what is actually going on in this piece of code. I'm guessing it's the latter, therefore I will try to explain it.

You have a `QImage`, then you have a `QByteArray`.

Then you create a `QBuffer` which gets the byte array you've created earlier as a parameter, `open`s it in Write-Only mode (because you will *write* the bytes into the array).

QImage has a function save which gets a buffer and a format (not mandatory). Then converts the image into the byte array. That's the main trick here, and what got you confused here I guess.

Note: I would personally prefer to open the image file as a `QFile` and read it into raw bytes with `readAll()`.

```
QFile* imageFile = new QFile("image.png");
imageFile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray ba = imageFile->readAll();
imageFile->close();
delete imageFile;
```

After that you can even access its raw data by calling `ba.data()`.

I hope that helps.

[You can read more about QImage::save function here.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#save-1)

Comment: Oh thanks! That can be good. But one question. Let's say that my image is 600x600 so it got 360,000 pixels, right ? And after reading data to array i got 72049 elements. So I guess that it read compressed data ?

Comment: @gawron103 What happens is that you are not reading the pixels, but the compressed pixels so that the size is not related to the pixels.

Comment: Bytes are a representation of the pixels, and the size of the byte array can vary greatlydepending on the compression/encoding. Shortly, you will be reading the raw byte representation of the image file, not pixels. But if you want to cast the bytes into an image later, that's completely another topic.